# Positive lookahead in HTML pattern?

Tags: html, regex

```
<input type="password" pattern="^(?=^[A-Z])(?=.{8,16})(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[1-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&-])">
```

I have this HTML but I can't seem to make my pattern work. I'm not sure if positive lookahead is supported or not or I'm not actually searching the whole string for the pattern.

**EDIT:**
This should pass: MySafe-Password1
This should fail: MySaferPassword

Comment: You kinda got it wrong, what is expected to pass this test? What is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All propositions are lookahead, it results an empty string, you have to keep one of them as "real":

```
"^(?=^[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[1-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&-]).{8,16}$"
```

Here I keep the length test.

Comment: All of them are "real", the point is that the pattern should consume the whole input string. A better idea is to use `"(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])(?=[^$@$!%*#?&-]*[$@$!%*#?&-])[A-Z].{7,15}"`. Anchors are added by HTML5 engine anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A general rule to verify a password is:

- Start with `^`.
- Put a number of positive lookaheads, for all conditions but the last.
- Put "ordinary" match for the last condition, usually concerning the length (e.g. `.{8,16}`).
- End with `$`.

So try:

```
^(?=[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[1-9])(?=.*[$@!%*#?&-]).{8,16}$
```

I think that:

- `(?=.*?[A-Z])` is unnecessary, as you have already checked for an
  upper case letter.
- There is no need to repeat `^` (in the first lookup).
- There is no need to repeat `$` (in the last lookup).
- The regex has to match something, so I moved `.{8,16}` to the end,
  (without lookup).

Comment: Nice explanation, this should be accepted answer, thought I would suggest to bold the second point as it is the answer.